# LSTM Input Data Preparation and Definition (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, spyder

There is a float data corresponding to each time step. Each recording data is a array of 1000 float numbers. Time is not recorded but its 0.1 sec between each recordings of data in array.

I want to prepare and store the data in an appropriate container and pass it to the LSTM Model.

Once without specifying the exact 0.1 sec duration and again with considering the duration.

What I've done:

I read the data from .mat file and appended each array of 1000 float to the list:

```
max_Value = []
min_Value = []
scale = 2.6
X_Data=[]
Y_Data=[]
epochs_Num = 10
batch_Num = 64
name_Model = f'{LSTM_{int(time.time())}'

for i_Path in origin_Data_Path:
    mat_Data = loadmat(i_Path)
    data     = mat_Data['data']
    X_Data.append(data[:,0])
    Y_Data.append(data[:,1])
 ...

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay=1e-6)
ls  = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f'logs/{name_Model}')

myModel.compile(loss=ls,optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

history = myModel.fit(X_Data,
                      labels_Categorical,
                      batch_size=batch_Num,
                      epochs=epochs_Num,
                      validation_split=0.2,
                      callbacks= [tensorboard]  )

myModel.save("myMod.h5")
```

**Error:**

```
  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Light/Desktop/Gesture/Test01.py", line 139, in <module>
    callbacks= [tensorboard]  )

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 224, in fit
    distribution_strategy=strategy)

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 516, in _process_training_inputs
    steps=steps_per_epoch)

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2472, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 565, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 1)
```

[X_Data ; structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QDpS.png)

[Data Struct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmx67.png)

Comment: What is `batch_Num`?

Comment: batch_Num = 64 and epochs_Num = 10

Comment: This is not the same problem causing code as posted before. Please can you clarify in your post what the new error is. Before you we're using a shape of (1000, 1). Please provide a definitive reproducible version of your problem with minimal changes please so we can work on the issue.

Comment: First post has been updated. Additional information about the error presented in Spyder console has been added. (I haven't changed the code except LSTM input shape parameters. 'just try and error')

Comment: Can you try expanding the 3rd dimension of xdata to be 1 instead of None please. This might be a bit tricky as you are using lists. I would strongly recommend converting to arrays. Using lists probably isn't helping and may even be the problem.

Comment: @JCooke 
This is the exact thing that I don't have idea about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to give it an input capable of being batched. You have given it `(1000, 1)` which seems to correspond to a single sample of your data. Keras wants it as `(batch/samples, time, channels)` which for you will be `(number of samples, 1000, 1)`. These are the 3 expected dimensions.

Check how you are constructing your input data. You do not need to make the batches up yourself, `fit()` will split up the input data into those size batches for you.

Comment: myModel.add(LSTM(256,batch_input_shape=(1476,1000,1),activation='relu',return_sequences=True))

Comment: thanks for reply. above statement cause error too. May I ask you provide me proper example for my problem? (I've updated the first post please check images, thanks)

Comment: can you please print X_data.shape and post output

Comment: X_Data is a list object and doesn't have shape attribute. But I also converted it to the data frame(-- train_Data = pd.DataFrame(X_Data) --) and the result was : (-- print(train_Data.shape) -- 
(1476, 1000) --)

Comment: ok well what is the shape of the X_Data list as that's what you pass the model, not whatever happens after pd

Comment: It's a list of arrays in the form of (float1,float2,float3, ... ,float999). You can also check the picture I've attached in the first post. thanks.

Comment: To make the post more clear I didn't attach whole the code. Should I do that?

Comment: Yes please so we can see how your data is put together.

Answer (score 0):

As I realized the container should be in the form of N-Dimentional Array. The problem with shape of input to the model is solved. But there is problems with low accuracy.